# Como usar "count se" no PHP

Tags: php

Preciso fazer um `count se` no `PHP`. Tenho uma tabela com vários status, e quero contar apenas determinado tipo. E preciso contar pelo PHP. Por `SQL` é inviável.

```
$data = Connection::Select('SELECT * FROM tabela');

$row = $data->fetchAll();

echo count($row->status === 1);

echo count($row->status === 2);

echo count($row->status === 3);
```

Tem como?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se REALMENTE quer contar no PHP vai precisar de algo assim:

```
$row = $data->fetchAll();

$i = 0;
foreach($row as $item) {
    if( $item['status'] === 1 ) ++$i;
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ aqui vai a condição desejada
}

echo $i; // $i tem o resultado total da contagem
```

Em SQL você pode fazer isto se quiser retornar tudo mas contar uma condição especial:

```
SELECT *, SUM( IF( campo atende condicao ), 1, 0 ) AS contados FROM tabela
```

Desta forma, tudo é retornado, mas o SUM vai somar 1 para as que atendem, 0 para as que não atendem, fazendo o papel de um `COUNT` condicional.

Notar que pelo volume de dados, pode não compensar fazer o `count` retornar a soma em todas as linhas, precisa escolher a melhor solução conforme o caso.

Se quiser a contagem separadamente, é só isso:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS contados FROM tabela WHERE status = condicao desejada
```

Comment: Exatamente isso @Bacco. Obrigado.

Comment: Qual é mais veloz? pelo if do php ou if interno no banco?

Comment: @RúbioFalcão A velocidade é desprezível, o mais importante é o contexto. Se vai iterar em todos os itens na tela no PHP, somar pelo PHP não custa nada. Se for pegar só o total, ai é besteira transmitir os dados todos do DB pro PHP, melhor fazer no SQL mesmo, pq ai só vem o resultado. O importante é entender o que está envolvido em cada caminho.